# "pyenv global" command does not change the python version. (M1 mac)

Tags: python, homebrew, pyenv

As you can see in the below command line, "pyenv global" command does not change anything.
Also, "python -V" command does not match the result of "pyenv versions".

```
% pyenv global 3.10.5
% pyenv versions
  system
  3.10.5
  3.5.4
* anaconda3-2019.07 (set by /Users/{userName}/.python-version)
% python -V
Python 3.7.3
```

Also, when I try to use python, it seems that my computer is usin python2, instead of python3, even though the version is 3.7.3.

```
a = 11 / 4

print(a) #should be 2.75 instead of 2
```

```
% python -u test.py
2
```

Comment: Did you check with your PATH, I could not reproduce the issue though.

Comment: ```
$ ls -al `which python`
-rwxr-xr-x  1 rui  staff  180 Dec  6  2021 /Users/rui/.pyenv/shims/python
```

Answer (score 0):

Does 'which python' point to the pyenv managed version such as

```
bob@Roberts-Mac-mini ~ % which python
/Users/bob/.pyenv/shims/python
```

do you have the correct pyenv environment set in your shell init files (bash, zsh etc) ? here is my example:

```
bob@Roberts-Mac-mini ~ % cat .zshrc
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```